# How can i highlight text given in any images and save the same image using html,css,js?

Tags: html, image, edit

I need to highlight text in an image uploaded on a website as per user requirement. I mean that a user should be able to highlight some text inside the uploaded image and the same should be saved. Can someone help me with the same? Is it possible using html,css,js?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the image and approach, if you are trying to change the text which is embedded on the image(simply image text) you cant do it using JS CSS or HTML.

If you have image and on top of it you are overlapping div/span element and showing text (which is not part of actual image) you can control the overlapped absolute text

Comment: I want to change the color of text  embedded inside the image. Could you please help me out in this scenario?

Comment: It's not possible because it's image, you can use Photoshop to change the image.